# Can TFS remind me of neceessary steps before allowing a Check-In

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, checkin

Is it possible to setup VS2012-TFS to force me (or remind me) to run a *Compare* before allowing a Check-IN?

Comment: You could extend the Team Explorer plugin? Use Check-In notes, or a custom check in policy. The former is quite a bit of work, the latter 2 impact your whole team.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a check-in policy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies). These check-in policies require the user to take actions when they conduct a check-in to source control, for example a user can be required to associate a work item with a changeset.

For your situation,you need to use [Customizing Check-In Policies and Creating Check-in Notes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181281) However, just as *DaveShaw* commented, this will impact your whole team.

If you only want this on your local machine, you may need to customize the team Explorer, such as add a prompt information in the check in page.How to achieve this you can refer this blog: [Extending Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201751.aspx)